# Advanced indexing for sympy?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

With numpy, I am able to select an arbitrary set of items from an array with a list of integers:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a[[0,2]]
array([1, 3])
```

The same does not seem to work with sympy matrices, as the code:

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> b = sp.Matrix([1,2,3])
>>> b[[0,2]]
```

results to an error message:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/dense.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    return self._mat[a2idx(key)]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/matrices/matrices.py", line 4120, in a2idx
    raise IndexError("Invalid index a[%r]" % (j, ))
IndexError: Invalid index a[[0, 2]]
```

My question is whether there would be a way to do this in sympy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `a` and `b` does not represent similar objects, actually `a` is a `1x3` "matrix" (one row, 3 columns), namely a vector, while `b` is a `3x1` matrix (3 rows, one column).

```
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b
Matrix([
[1],
[2],
[3]])
```

The `numpy` equivalent would be `numpy.array([[1], [2], [3]])`, not your `a`.

Knowing that, `b[[0,2]]` has no meaning because you are missing index for one of your dimension. If you want to select only the first and third rows, you need to specify the second dimension:

```
>>> b[[0, 2], :]
Matrix([
[1],
[3]])
```

**Note**: Using `numpy`, you could access a `3x1` matrix the way you want, it looks like `simply` is more strict than `numpy`.

Comment: That is right, I also tested it with numpy matrices but forgot to add that into the question. So indeed it seems that sympy is more strict with the slicing notation and explicitly requires the second dimension. With that, it seems to work like a charm. Thank you very much!